# "AM_PROG_LIBTOOL" not found in library

Tags: autoconf, automake, libtool

I got an error while trying to compile a library in centOS 7, and i tried reinstall libtool but it does not help. Below is the error

```
+ autoreconf --install
configure.ac:32: warning: macro 'AM_PROG_LIBTOOL' not found in library
configure.ac:32: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_LIBTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might need: `autoreconf -fvi` to make sure everything is updated.

It's also worth noting that `AM_PROG_LIBTOOL` is deprecated, and should be replaced with [`LT_INIT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#LT_005fINIT), and optionally with `LT_PREREQ` beforehand.

Comment: since what version of libtool is AM_PROG_LIBTOOL deprecated in favour of LT_INIT? do you know? I ask because, before I replace it with LT_INIT in my project, I guess I should require this version in LT_PREREQ() call first

Comment: @knocte - If it's *your* project, then there's no reason why you shouldn't be using the latest autotools to generate the build system. At this time: `LT_PREREQ([2.4.6])`

Comment: there's always a reason to require older versions instead of latest: reach to a bigger audience of systems/devs, so I want to know the oldest version that supported LT_INIT

Comment: (`my project` can also mean `open source`, not internal ;) )

Comment: @knocte - but if you `make dist` - i.e., distribute the build system created by *applying* the autotools - the end user doesn't need to have the autotools installed. Which is the whole point:)

Comment: well, by `end user` I mean the developer that git clones my project, not the one that installs the tarball

Comment: @knocte - I myself think it's reasonable to expect anyone who is using the autotools in 'maintainer' mode to have the latest versions installed. [Opinions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675547/using-git-for-distribution-with-autotools) will vary about this.

Comment: why don't you just say that you don't know the first autoconf version that introduced LT_INIT? :)

Comment: @knocte - because I don't know off-hand. Why not just grep the ChangeLog?

Comment: it turns out it's not as easy as you think, the first mention of LT_INIT is: `2004-02-23  Gary V. Vaughan  <gary [[at]] gnu.org>

 * bin/autoreconf.in (autoreconf_current_directory): Recognize LT_INIT
 from the next generation of Libtool.` But not sure what version is that commit included in, and not sure if that's really the correct commit.

Answer (score 35):

I solved it just by:

sudo yum install libtool

Comment: I got the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04. `sudo apt install libtool` worked for me

Comment: I got the same problem on Windows msys2, `pacman -S libtool` works.